# mysql misses data entry

Tags: php, mysql, database

Im trying to stress test mysql:

```
 for($i=0;$i<30000;$i++)
{
 mysql_connect("localhost","admin","admin");
 mysql_select_db("magic");
 mysql_query(INSERT INTO Persons
 VALUES   (4,'9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999'));
 mysql_close(); 
}
```

It only inserts 25985, not more. 
Table schema : id = primary int, content = long text

Tt gives me `error cannot connect to mysql`, even though I increase the max connections.

Any solution would be appreciated :)

Comment: I don't understand what is your point? Apparently it can't handle this much 'stress' You could try to put a Sleep() in the for statement so it takes a little time before it goes to the next one? http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: In a real time scenario there could be thousands of request in one second , so how does it handle it ? I tried nosql and it  inserts 30,000 but mysql does not

Comment: yes but the 25985 data is right data, and each time the for loop runs it makes a new connection and closes it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The amount of connection is damn to high !" Kidding !

The number of connection is provided by the number of RAM available on your computer. So if you have gygabites of RAM you can have like 10k connections, depend on your system, the RAM allowed to your connection etc.

Check it here : [MYSQL : too many connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/too-many-connections.html)

> The maximum number of connections MySQL can support depends on the quality of the thread library on a given platform, the amount of RAM available, how much RAM is used for each connection, the workload from each connection, and the desired response time.

Why do you need so much connections at the same time ? One connection and 30.000 insertions should be OK but not 30.000 connections at the same time.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Try to open only one connection and insert all in the loop and close it after the connection.

Comment: but he closes the connections each time, he shouldn't have a too many connections problem...

Comment: Closing connection doesn't mean empty the RAM. Maybe the RAM is empty after doing the script and not during doing the script. The garbage collector is certainly executed at the end of the script and not at the end of each instruction in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because you open and close a connection on every loop iteration. In most implementations, caching is used so as not to frequently re-establish a connection.

```
mysql_connect("localhost","admin","admin");
mysql_select_db("magic");
for($i=0;$i<30000;$i++)
{
    mysql_query(INSERT INTO Persons
    VALUES   (4,'9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999'));
}
mysql_close();
```